# Iterows replacement for a calculation between each row of one dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I'm trying to move away from iterows due to it's poor proformance. I can't however find another solution to comparing each row of one dataframe with each row from another dataframe.

I have two dataframes each containing a latitude and a longitude. Previously I have used these two functions to make a distance calculation between the two coordinates shown here:

```
def find_matches(first_HL, second_HL, N, M):
    program_start = time.time()
    matched_sites_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for i_WP, r_WP in first_HL.iterrows():
        series = pd.Series(dtype=float)
        if r_WP['PL Name'] is not None and r_WP['PL Latitude'] is not None and r_WP['PL Longitude'] is not None:
            series = name_and_distance_match(i_WP, r_WP, second_HL, N, M)
            if series is not None:
                series = pd.DataFrame(series.to_frame().T)
                matched_sites_df = pd.concat([matched_sites_df, series], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    
                now = time.time()
                print("------ MATCH FOUND ------ ", r_WP['PL Name'], "------", round(now - program_start, 2), "seconds")
    return matched_sites_df

def calc_distance(r_WP, r_HL):
    coords_1 = (r_WP['PL Latitude'], r_WP['PL Longitude'])
    coords_2 = (r_HL['Latitude'], r_HL['Longitude'])
    distance_km = round(geopy.distance.geodesic(coords_1, coords_2).km, 2)
    return distance_km

def name_and_distance_match(i_WP, r_WP, second_HL, N, M):
    for i_HL, r_HL in second_HL.iterrows():
        if pd.isnull(r_HL['Site Name']) or pd.isnull(r_WP['PL Name']) == True:
            pass
        elif abs(r_WP['PL Latitude'] - r_HL['Latitude']) > 0.1:
            pass
        elif abs(r_WP['PL Longitude'] - r_HL['Longitude']) > 0.1:
            pass
        else:
            distance_km = r_WP['Distance (km)'] = calc_distance(r_WP, r_HL)
            if distance_km < M:
                r_HL = filter_town(r_WP, r_HL)
                score = r_WP['Name Similarity'] = np.vectorize(fuzzy)(r_HL["HL Site Short"], r_WP['PL Name'])
                if score > N:
                    r_WP["HL Site Short"] = r_HL["HL Site Short"]
                    return r_WP
```

Is there a way I can do this without iterows?
The solution I'm working on at the moment looks like this:

```
def distance_check(first_HL, second_WPHL):
    first_lat = first_HL["Latitude"]
    first_long = second_WPHL["PL Longitude"]
    second_lat = first_HL["Latitude"]
    second_long = second_WPHL["PL Longitude"]
    if abs(first_lat - second_lat) + abs(first_long - second_long) > 0.2:
        return False
    else:
        COMBINED_HOUSELIST["WHATPUB Site Name"] = PUBMATCH_WHATPUB_SITES["Site Name"]
        return True

PUBMATCH_WHATPUB_SITES
COMBINED_HOUSELIST["Distance Check"] = COMBINED_HOUSELIST.apply(distance_check(PUBMATCH_WHATPUB_SITES, COMBINED_HOUSELIST), axis=1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: Example Dataframes

```
COMBINED_HOUSELIST = pd.DataFrame(np.array([["12345", "Wrexham Cwtch", "52.10", "-2.06"], ["12354", "Horse & Hound", "52.21", "-1.95"], ["12435", "Round Of Gras Badsey", "52.33", "-1.99"]]),
                   columns=['Site Number', 'Site Name', 'Longitude', 'Latitude'])

PUBMATCH_WHATPUB_SITES= pd.DataFrame(np.array([["52938", "Valkyrie Café Bar", "53.22", "-3.00"], ["12435", "Round Of Badsey", "52.33", "-1.99"], ["12345", "Cwtch", "52.11", "-2.00"]]),
                   columns=['Site Number', 'Site Name', 'Longitude', 'Latitude'])
```

Desired output

```
matched_sites = pd.DataFrame(np.array([["12345", "Wrexham Cwtch", "52.10", "-2.06"], ["12354", "Horse & Hound", "52.21", "-1.95"], ["12435", "Round Of Gras Badsey", "52.33", "-1.99"]]),
                   columns=['Site Number', 'Site Name', 'Longitude', 'Latitude'])
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Laurent thanks for looking at this, I've edited the questions with example dataframes

Comment: Hi, I've made an edit again to show the example calculation. In this case for ease I have considered it a pass if the the two lats and two longs have an absolute value of equal to or less than 0.1. This would mean that the desired output with the pubs within the desired lat and long would be;
Wrexham Cwtch & Cwtch
"Horse & Hound" & Cwtch
Round Of Gras Badsey & Round Of Badsey

Comment: "Horse & Hound" & "Cwtch" gives 0.15, which is > 0.1, so, unless I missed something, it should not be a match. I have posted an answer based on a correct example as I understand it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

One way or another, I fear that you will have to resort to some form of iteration, but doing it outside of Pandas might speed things up.

So, here is one way to do it with [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) functions from Python standard library.

First, define two helper functions:

```py
from functools import partial


def calc_distance(coo1, coo2):
    return abs(coo1[0] - coo2[0]) + abs(coo1[1] - coo2[1])


def find_matches(one_list, another_list, threshold):
    idx = []
    for coo in one_list:
        func = partial(calc_distance, coo)
        results = [result for result in map(func, another_list)]
        idx.append([results.index(result) for result in results if result <= threshold])
    return idx
```

Then, with the following toy dataframes:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


COMBINED_HOUSELIST = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array(
        [
            ["12345", "Wrexham Cwtch", "52.10", "-2.06"],
            ["12354", "Horse & Hound", "52.21", "-1.95"],
            ["12435", "Round Of Gras Badsey", "52.33", "-1.99"],
        ]
    ),
    columns=["Site Number", "Site Name", "Longitude", "Latitude"],
)

PUBMATCH_WHATPUB_SITES = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array(
        [
            ["52938", "Valkyrie Café Bar", "53.22", "-3.00"],
            ["54999", "New Café Bar", "52.10", "-2.1"],
            ["12435", "Round Of Badsey", "52.33", "-1.99"],
            ["12345", "Cwtch", "52.11", "-2.00"],
        ]
    ),
    columns=["Site Number", "Site Name", "Longitude", "Latitude"],
)
```

You can proceed like this:

```py
# Setup
for col in ["Latitude", "Longitude"]:
    for df in [COMBINED_HOUSELIST, PUBMATCH_WHATPUB_SITES]:
        df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col])

# Get two lists of coordinates looking like [[lat, long], [lat, long],...]
CH_COO = COMBINED_HOUSELIST.loc[:, ["Latitude", "Longitude"]].to_dict("split")["data"]
PW_COO = PUBMATCH_WHATPUB_SITES.loc[:, ["Latitude", "Longitude"]].to_dict("split")[
    "data"
]

# Look for matches
COMBINED_HOUSELIST = COMBINED_HOUSELIST.assign(match=find_matches(CH_COO, PW_COO, 0.1))

# Get site names
COMBINED_HOUSELIST["match"] = COMBINED_HOUSELIST.apply(
    lambda x: [PUBMATCH_WHATPUB_SITES.loc[idx, "Site Name"] for idx in x["match"]],
    axis=1,
)
```

Finally, `print(COMBINED_HOUSELIST)`:

[image]